# What is Tunnel adapter isatap?

Tags: windows, mac-address

Hi i am working MAC address of machine. I have created a Application which gives me MAC ADDRESS for that machine.

I have observe that every machine on which i have tested i got Following physical address in every machine

```
Tunnel adapter isatap.{80A45D7C-0F1D-4270-83DC-B03014CF06A1}:


   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

i have to work with this

```
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
```

Can anybody please explain me about this,so that i can decide whether i can skip this physical address

Comment: Just Google, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISATAP): "ISATAP (Intra-Site Automatic Tunnel Addressing Protocol) is an IPv6 transition mechanism meant to transmit IPv6 packets between dual-stack nodes on top of an IPv4 network."

Comment: Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
is common in all machine??

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular protocol, but if the link layer is point-to-point, or more likely isn't used at all, then there's no need for unique physical addresses.